# How did you or your advisor’s behavior change after obtaining tenure

Tags: tenure-track

I am curious (if you are a professor) how you changed consciously or unconsciously after obtaining tenure and (if you are a student) how did your advisor change and did that affect you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a hard question to answer as a lot of things have changed simultaneously. For one thing I have just grown older (that makes me sound very old), got married, became a dad. All of these things affect who I am and how I view and interact with other people. My time as a PhD student was for me the first time in and employment relationship. Since than I got experience with other work positions, other bosses, and been a boss myself. This again changes how I view my advisor, independent of having tenure or not. At the time my dissertation was very very very important to me and this has decreased over time as well. I suspect that these changes were a lot more important in how my view of my advisor changed than the type of my employment contract.